# How to use the same Anonymous user on Firebase?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I want a guest user to login, and create only 1 new user on my auth db.

Problem-

- **-On Unity editor-** A new anonymous user is created with each launch of the app
- **On Android** the guest user stays logged in but when the app is uninstalled- then another new anonymous user is created

My db is just full of anonymous users.

Note- I do use- and check monitoring authentication state

How can I use the same Anonymous user? I was even thinking about login with a custom token, and save it on the user's device- but then I need to create my own uid on the admin side and not sure if it's reliable or even a good solution?

It seems like Firebase doesn't give a proper solution for that. You'd think it's basic. Am I missing something?

Code for unity-

```
void InitializeFirebase()
{
    Debug.Log("Setting up Firebase Auth");

    auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
    auth.StateChanged += AuthStateChanged;
    AuthStateChanged(this, null);
}

void AuthStateChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (auth.CurrentUser != user)
    {
         bool signedIn = user != auth.CurrentUser && auth.CurrentUser != null;
        if (!signedIn && user != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Signed out " + user.UserId);
        }
        user = auth.CurrentUser;
        if (signedIn)
        {
            Debug.Log("Signed in " + user.UserId);
        }
    }
}

void OnDestroy()
{
    auth.StateChanged -= AuthStateChanged;
    auth = null;
}
   public static void SignAnonymous()
{
  auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
  auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
  user = task.Result;

        Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
        user.DisplayName, user.UserId);
    });

}
```

Comment: If you want help figuring out why your approach isn't working, include the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question. That drastically increases the chances that somebody can spot what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen ! but my question is not just code related. It's known that Firebase creates new anonymous users when the app is uninstalled and installed again (and probably some other times also). I can't trust firebase or prevent it from creating new users for a device. It spams my db. Therefore I want to manage it myself and asked how to use the same anonymous user or what is another way to create a single anonymous user per device. Could custom tokens be an option? I added my code now

Comment: Where do you call `SignAnonymous`? You should only call this when the user is not signed in yet. Although (if I recall correctly) calling it even when the user is signed in already should not create a new UID, but merely reload the existing one. The only time that I know that might not happen is if the SDK is unable to store the user token locally on the device.  Ah, I now see that is precisely your first bullet.

Comment: Yes I check if the user is logged in- but on Unity-editor, it'll always return false when re-launching the app, and on Android it'd be false as well after uninstalling the app (and I suspect other times as well) therefore anonymous user is not a good option

Comment: Firebase keeps it's user token on the device. But of course it is wiped from there when the user deletes the app. With your own custom sign-in method, where are you going to keep the user ID/credentials so that they don't get wiped, yet don't require the user to sign in again?

Answer (score 0):

store device id in firebase database and every time you sing in using anonymous sign in method, you can retrieve the same data. i don't think firebase let's us use same anonymous user id to use again and again right now.